# Redirect from https to http without having a certificate for my website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all of the following urls:

```
1- https://www.example.com
2- http://www.example.com
3- example.com
```

to this single url

www.example.com

This is the htaccess but its not working for the https case. I still don't have a certificate but don't want users to see the warning page until I can sort that out.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] [R=301,L]

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
     RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.uk$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.uk
     RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    <Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The negotiation of certificate is done first.  Then the other configurations are applied.  So your redirection will only be applied after you get the certificate warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bypass the security warning, because the security warning is generated by the browser upon detecting an invalid certificate.

When connecting to a website over https, the first step is to set up the keys required to encrypt and decrypt the data that will be sent. It is the task of the client (in this case the browser) to verify that the keys that are being used for encryption and decryption are valid. That means that the certificate was given out for the domain it wants to send/receive data from/to, that the certificate has not expired, the certificate has not been retracted and that the certificate was signed by someone that the client trusts. All this happens before the browser receives any non-protocol data from the server.

The only possible solution to your problem is to install a valid certificate for your website. You can install a free certificate using LetsEncrypt. Refer to their website for more information on how to set up the certificate, and how to set up automatic renewal.